# createElement + createTextNode oneliner?

Tags: javascript

I'm adding a few thousand rows to a table so i need the speed of native javascript for this one.

Currently I'm using:

```
nThName = document.createElement("TH");
nThName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(workers[i].name));
nTr.appendChild(nThName);
```

**Is there a way to do this in one line (without losing any performance?) so I don't need the nThName variable?**

There are over 50 cells on each row so I would prefer:

```
nTr.appendChild(document.createElement("TH").appendChild(document.createTextNode(workers[i].name)));
```

but that don't work.. obviously

Comment: Why not simply create a single, and simple, function that performs this task and then simply call that function when you need to?

Comment: Using Davids fiddle, just add [`.parentNode`](http://jsfiddle.net/2bJkq/1/)   (though I'd really go with a helper function...)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

So, you're looking for performance? One-liners don't help with that. Using document fragments and cloning nodes *does* help, however. But it requires a bit more code.

```
var table = document.getElementById('t');
var tr = table.querySelector('tr');
var th = document.createElement('th');
var clone;

var df = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    // Performance tip: clone a node so that you don't reuse createElement()
    clone = th.cloneNode();
    clone.appendChild(document.createTextNode('hello' + i));

    // Performance tip: append to the document fragment
    df.appendChild(clone);
}

// Performance tip: append only once in the real DOM
tr.appendChild(df);
```

See jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3KGwh/3/

Document fragments are basically mini-DOM, with limited methods. They're great because they allow you to get *great* performance, and you can append a single element to the real DOM.

Comment: This may not answer my question but it has some really good tips. Thanks!

Comment: The createDocumentFragment is actually an element.. without the element, right? I'm first creating my tbody and appending my TR's to that. When all done, i'm appending it to the DOM. It's the same thing as above with the createDocumentFragment, right?

Comment: @TieleDeclercq yes, indeed

Comment: When adding empty elements. May I appendChild(th) without cloning? Or should I always clone?

Comment: @TieleDeclercq if you don't clone, it will remain the same element. Appending an element to another moves it.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done, as an example:

```
document.body.appendChild(
    document.createElement('div').appendChild(
        document.createTextNode('hello')
    ).parentNode
);
```

[JS Fiddle representative demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3KGwh/1/).

I think it's just your approach to chaining that was off; given your specific demo code:

```
nTr.appendChild(
    document.createElement('th').appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(workers[i].name)
    ).parentNode
);
```

The white-space here isn't essential, it's simply to more-clearly show what goes where.

Comment: 'inspect element' on your fiddle.. you'll see that 'hello' is not inside your div

Comment: Corrected (following @Yoshi's [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775976/createelement-createtextnode-oneliner?noredirect=1#comment36563830_23775976)); now 'inspect element' *does* reveal that 'hello' is inside the appended `div` element.

Answer (score 0):

like David Thomas suggested.. a helper function is clearly the best option:

```
nTr.appendChild(newElement("TH", workers[i].name));

function newElement(TagName, TextContent, ClassName) {
    var nTag = document.createElement(TagName);
    nTag.className = ClassName;
    nTag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(TextContent));
    return nTag;
}
```

Changed it with advice by Florian Margaine. Result is super fast. MANY times faster then pure knockout or jquery.

```
var tplTbody = document.createElement("TBODY");
var tplTr = document.createElement("TR");
var tplTd = document.createElement("TD"); // Every element used has it's 'template'

var nTbody = tplTbody.cloneNode();
for(var i in rows) {
    var nTr = newElement(tplTr.cloneNode(), null, "someclass");
    for(var i in cells) {
        nTr.appendChild(newElement(tplTd.cloneNode(), cell[i].content);
    }
    nTbody.appendChild(nTr);
}
document.getElementById("myTable").appendChild(nTbody);


function newElement(Tag, TextContent, ClassName) {
    if (TextContent !== undefined && TextContent != null)
        Tag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(TextContent));
    if (ClassName !== undefined && ClassName != null) 
        Tag.className = ClassName;
    return Tag;
}
```

Comment: It's not the best option for performance to use `document.createElement` and `appendChild` in a loop though :)