# Document.createElement() vs Document.createTextNode() - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to figure out what is the differences between this two:

```
// first one
var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
var t = document.createTextNode('hey');
h1.appendChild(t);
document.body.appendChild(h1);

// second one
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('h1').appendChild(document.createTextNode('hey')));
```

The first ([Document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)) works perfectly, but the second ([Document.createTextNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode)) does not.

Comment: Because `appendChild` returns the appended node, so you're trying to append a text node to body...

Comment: the result of `document.createElement('h1').appendChild(document.createTextNode('hey')` is the text node ... therefore you are appending the text node to the body

Comment: [Document.createElement + Document.createTextNode one-liner?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775976/createelement-createtextnode-oneliner)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of `appendChild` is the appended child.

So if we add variables to:

> ```
> document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('h1').appendChild(document.createTextNode('hey')));
> ```

it gets broken down into:

```
var text = document.createTextNode('hey');
var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
h1.appendChild(text);
document.body.appendChild(text);
```

Appending the `text` to the `body` removes the `text` from the `h1`.

The `h1` is discarded because it is never appended anywhere.

Comment: Now, let's assume i'm starting with `document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('h1'));` and this h1 tag doesn't have id, so how can I add to this tag some text?

Comment: You'd have to search the document for it. Use a variable. Don't try to stuff multiple operations into a single statement.

Comment: OK. Iv'e tried to code it in one line because I need to build an entire html page in JS. :)

Comment: h1.innerText does the same thing as working with text nodes, and is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to do it: (just add .parentNode at the end)

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('h1').appendChild(document.createTextNode('hey')).parentNode);
```